# CSipSimple - java.lang.SecurityException : Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.Phone_State

Tags: android, voip, android-4.4-kitkat, pjsip, csip-simple

CSipSimple. Help Required. I'm trying to build a VoIP application that enables a user to call any device in the WLAN thrugh CSipSimple's local wizard. Here's the error I get on clicking the call button on Kitkat(4.4.2) CM 11.

java.lang.SecurityException : Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.Phone_State . Help me out.

I'm attaching the log file for reference.

```
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207): FATAL EXCEPTION: UAStateAsyncWorker
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207): Process: com.csipsimple:sipStack, PID: 13207
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE from pid=13207, uid=10271
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2392)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1205)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:370)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at com.csipsimple.pjsip.UAStateReceiver.broadCastAndroidCallState(UAStateReceiver.java:910)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at com.csipsimple.pjsip.UAStateReceiver.access$3(UAStateReceiver.java:902)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at com.csipsimple.pjsip.UAStateReceiver$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(UAStateReceiver.java:749)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-26 16:17:12.236: E/AndroidRuntime(13207):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
02-26 16:17:12.246: E/libpjsip(13207): 16:17:12.252   pjsua_call.c !.Unable to send initial INVITE request: gethostbyname() has returned error (PJ_ERESOLVE) [status=70018]
```

Answer (score 0):

add following line in manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```